# onPress not working on Animatable component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is anything jumping out as wrong here? I am trying to have an `onPress` behavior on my Animatable component so when i drag it around with a gesture it will move, but if i click it it will fire that onPress behavior ...

It's currently a `TouchableOpacity` because that is what another stackoverflow answer suggested, yet when I use the `createAnimatedComponent` function with a `TouchableOpacity` I lose the ability to actually move it with gestures.

Any ideas?

```
return (
      <AnimatedTouchable
        style={[
          styles.card,
          this.state.active ? { zIndex: 2 } : { zIndex: 1 },
          {
            transform: [
              { translateX: this._animatedValue.x },
              { translateY: this._animatedValue.y },
              { rotate: interpolatedRotation },
              { scaleX: this.scale },
              { scaleY: this.scale }
            ]
          }
        ]}
        onPress={this.sayHi}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        <Text style={styles.cardNumber}>{this.props.id}</Text>
      </AnimatedTouchable>
    );
```

`const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);`

With this current setup it only fires the onPress function, but non of my gesture animations go through.

Comment: For me it's working as expected https://snack.expo.io/@jdnichollsc/animatable

Answer (score 0):

`Animated` does not support it. It may not cause errors, but functions may not work properly.

`createAnimatedComponent()` can be used to make a component animatable.

- `Animated` exports the following animatable components using the
  above wrapper:
- Animated.Image
- Animated.ScrollView
- Animated.Text
- Animated.View
- Animated.FlatList
- Animated.SectionList

You can change this

```js
<Animated.View>
  <TouchableOpacity>
     <Text style={styles.cardNumber}>{this.props.id}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>`
```

Comment: I believe I've tried solutions like this in the past and any gestures I set on the parent Animate.View would block my access to the child onPress button. In your example are you able to gesture animate the parent and still have onPress access to the child button?

Comment: You say means, Does TouchableOffacity's Onpress work properly?

Comment: onPress doesn't propagate trough <Animated> component... If a eg. button is wrapped in <Animated.View>, nothing happens

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? @WolfWar

Comment: @ugrdursun I think I changed the concept to avoid this situation... but no, I didn't find solution

Comment: Check the solution https://snack.expo.io/@jdnichollsc/animatable

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component with an `AnimatableView` and use a ref in order to execute the animation, example:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import {
  View as AnimatableView,
  initializeRegistryWithDefinitions
} from 'react-native-animatable'
import { throttle } from 'lodash'
import { ANIMATIONS } from '../animations'

export default function (WrappedComponent) {
  return ({ onPress, delay = 800, duration = 1000, animation = ANIMATIONS.ZOOM_IN_OUT, ...rest }) => {
    const compEl = useRef(null)
    const onPressAnimatedDelayed = throttle((event) => {
      onPress && onPress(event)
      compEl.current.animate(animation, duration)
    }, delay, { 'trailing': false })

    return (
      <AnimatableView ref={compEl}>
        <WrappedComponent
          onPress={onPressAnimatedDelayed}
          {...rest}
        />
      </AnimatableView>
    )
  }
}
```

Check the example running from Expo: https://snack.expo.io/@jdnichollsc/animatable

Regards